# Netbeans with xdebug

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, netbeans, xdebug

I have a weird problem. I have Netbeans 7.2 and xdebug installed. I try to run a debug session but Netbeans says I have to update "Netbeans Connector Chrome Extension". Strange thing is that I have the newest version of this extension and I've ran the session just a moment ago.

On the other hand I'd like to run the session using Firefox but Netbeans always asks for Chrome extension - nevermind what browser is set to default or even what browser is configured to run in Netbeans settings.

How can I solve this?

Comment: experiencing same problem - update required error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont know about 7.2 but i just spent an hour to find out how to debug with xdebug on 7.4.
So netbeans connector is needed for stuff like live edit, js debug etc (not sure whether it can be used for xdebug also, the extension worked only once for me). If you only want to use xdebug you dont need the connector extension. Netbeans made debuging very weird and if you want to control which debug mode you use you need to select the browser for the Project. So if you want to debug PHP with xdebug:

1. Go to project properties
2. Browser (on the left)
3. Select Firefox or Chrome (but not Chrome with Nebeans connector)
4. Ofcourse you need to setup xdebug on php side. There are lot of posts here.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Step 2 in your list should now be "Choose Run" in the properties window. Appears that Netbeans has updated their UI. Thanks for the tip! It resolved my issue with using the Netbeans Connector extension.